# Remote analytics tracking for multiple sites

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I am trying to track some basic data from multiple domains (Monthly hits, Session length, etc). Each domain is owned by a client, and it is a business requirement for me to have access to their statistics.

I have the access needed to add in a tracking code to each domain, similar to GA's tracking code. Each of these should transmit data to my master server, which consolidates and stores the info.

What would be the best way to go about doing this? Is this sort of tracker best built from scratch, or is there an open source analytics provider which can meet this specific use case? (Many tracking end-points, single database)

I will be aggregating the visits, duration, etc for each user separately, so as to compare and rank them against each other.

Answer (score 2):

Hello Sainath Krishnan,

In general terms, it all depends on how you want to see these data: whether you want to aggregate all the sites together, whether you want to see the users as only one across these multiple sites, and so on.

For instance, since you've installed the proper tracking code, which you administrate, on these site, you will be able to see all sort of traffic data that these tracking codes will send to your Google Analytics account and properties.

Could you be more specific regarding the way you want to see the data, or even if you'll deal with goals os specifics KPI's ?

Comment: Hey! Sorry, I will edit my question to make it clearer! I meant, I have the access to install the tracking code on all these domains. My question is more to do with how I can build the tracking mechanism to start with!